# Unable to compile Omnet++ in Ubuntu 16.04 - make errors

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, g++

I've followed installation instructions mentioned in:

https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf

Then followed the instructions mentioned in:

http://vikashmainanwal.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/omnet-simulator-installation-steps-in.html

To install simulator IDE itself.

When reaching the `make` phase, the following errors are produced:

```
Creating shared library: /home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/lib/gcc/liboppqtenv.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/src/qtenv'
cd /home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/src/envir && make opp_run_executable
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/src/envir'
Creating executable: /home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/out/gcc-release/src/envir/opp_run_release
/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/lib/gcc/liboppqtenv.so: undefined reference to `osgViewer::CompositeViewer::readConfiguration(std::string const&)'
/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/lib/gcc/liboppsim.so: undefined reference to `osg::Node::getDescription(unsigned int)'
/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/lib/gcc/liboppqtenv.so: undefined reference to `osgEarth::Viewpoint::Viewpoint(std::string const&, double, double, double, double, double, double, osgEarth::SpatialReference const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:118: recipe for target '/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/out/gcc-release/src/envir/opp_run_release' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/out/gcc-release/src/envir/opp_run_release] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/src/envir'
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'base' failed
make[1]: *** [base] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/adiel/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0'
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'allmodes' failed
make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
```

`gcc --version` output:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04) 4.9.4
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Because I don't need 3D visualization, I build Omnet++ without osgEarth and OpenSceneGraph (and QtEnv):

```
./configure WITH_OSGEARTH=no WITH_OSG=no WITH_QTENV=no
make -j3
```

With that build of Omnet++ I was able to execute the samples.